# Arduino Leonardo doesn't print anything to Serial Monitor with my specific code

Tags: serial, arduino-leonardo

I did a project with an Arduino Leonardo and a fingerprint sensor (DY50).
When I uploaded the `enroll` example from the `Adafruit Fingerprint Library` and saved my fingerprint, everything worked. But when I upload my code, it doesn't print anything.

**My Code**

```
#include <Keyboard.h>
#include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>
#define mySerial Serial1

Adafruit_Fingerprint finger = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&mySerial);
int fingerprintID = 0;
String inData;
bool isRight;
int pos;

//Number of services to log in
#define servNum 5

//Login URLs for Google, Amazon, Stackoverflow, Arduino and Github
String LogInURL[] = {"https://accounts.google.com/signin", "https://www.amazon.de/ap/signin", "https://stackoverflow.com/users/login", "https://login.arduino.cc/", "https://github.com/login"};
String LogInUser[] = {"user.name@gmail.com", "user.name@example.com", "user.name@example.com", "username", "username"};
String LogInPwd[] = {"password", "password", "password", "password", "password"};

void donothing() {};

void StepsBefore(int serviceNum){
  switch(serviceNum){
    case 0: donothing(); break;
    case 1: donothing(); break;
    case 2: for(int k=0; k<18; k++) Keyboard.press(KEY_TAB); Keyboard.release(KEY_TAB); break;
    case 3: for(int k=0; k<2; k++) Keyboard.press(KEY_TAB); Keyboard.release(KEY_TAB); break;
    case 4: donothing(); break;
    default: Serial.println("Error: Number not recognized."); break;
  }
}

void StepsAfter(int serviceNum){
  switch(serviceNum){
    case 0: Keyboard.println(); break;
    case 1: Keyboard.println(); break;
    case 2: Keyboard.press(KEY_TAB); Keyboard.release(KEY_TAB); break;
    case 3: Keyboard.press(KEY_TAB); Keyboard.release(KEY_TAB); break;
    case 4: for(int k=0; k<2; k++) Keyboard.press(KEY_TAB); Keyboard.release(KEY_TAB); break;
    default: Serial.println("Error: Number not recognized."); break;
  }
}

int getFingerprintIDez() {
  uint8_t p = finger.getImage();
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;
  p = finger.image2Tz();
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;
  p = finger.fingerFastSearch();
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;
  Serial.print("Found ID #"); 
  Serial.print(finger.fingerID); 
  Serial.print(" with confidence of "); 
  Serial.println(finger.confidence);
  return finger.fingerID; 
}

void askForFingerprint() {
  fingerprintID = getFingerprintIDez();
    delay(50);
    if(fingerprintID == 1){
      isRight = true;
    }
}

void delAfterChar(String inString, String fromToKill){
  pos = inString.indexOf(fromToKill);
  inString.remove(pos, 1000);
  inData = inString;
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("Debug 1");
    Keyboard.begin();
    Serial.println("Debug 2");
    finger.begin(57600);
    Serial.println("Debug 3");
    if(finger.verifyPassword()) {
        Serial.println("Found fingerprint sensor!");
    } 
    else {
        Serial.println("Did not find fingerprint sensor :(");
        while (1) { delay(1); }
    }
}
void loop() {
  inData = Serial.read();
  delAfterChar(inData, "?openid"); //Amazon
  delAfterChar(inData, "/v2/"); //Google
  delAfterChar(inData, "?ssrc"); //Stackoverflow
  delAfterChar(inData, "login?state"); //Arduino
    for (int i=0; i<servNum; i++){
     if(inData == LogInURL[i]){
        askForFingerprint();
        if(isRight == true){
           StepsBefore(i);
           Keyboard.print(LogInUser[i]);
           StepsAfter(i);
           Keyboard.println(LogInPwd[i]);
        }
        else Serial.println("Finger not recognized");
     }
    }
}
```

**What I've tried so far**

- I changed the baud rate from `9600` to `15200`, didn't help
- Added a few debug points in the `setup` to check for an error there, nothing changed
- Uploaded a simple Hello World via Serial Monitor sketch, worked perfectly

**Question**
What could be the issue? It compiles with no error message. If you see any coding mistakes, feedback would be great.

**EDIT**
Using `SoftwareSerial` instead didn't help either.

Comment: @jsotola I did that, as explained in the third point of what I've already tried. Sorry if it's not understandable, I don't speak English natively.

Comment: add `while (!Serial);` after Serial.begin

Comment: Thanks, @Juraj, totally forgot about this. But why did printing `Hello World` work without that?

Comment: the Hello World print was in loop? it doesn't take long to connect, but the code runs fast

Comment: @Juraj Yes, it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Juraj pointed out, I just forgot to use `while (!Serial)` in the `setup`, probably because I use other boards that don't need this more often.